# Enlightenment and Creation. Your analysis?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, theology, eastern-philosophy

For all the eastern philosophies and many other religions, the goal of life is enlightenment, which means insight or awakening to the true nature of reality.

Would it not have been easier to not create the whole system - souls, time, matter/energy? Instead the God could have just understood oneself without creating these sub-particles.

But still God decided to create the world.  Why?

Comment: instead of voting down can we explain why we are voting down (then maybe vote down)?

Comment: Well, I suppose that's because the premises are fallacious. Also, questions should be supported by facts. @user1244649: How, do you think, can we even begin to realise why God did, what he did if he did it? And why would he choose the "easiest" way? What should he have understood then, without creation? And why do you think that God seeks enlightenment the way we humans do?

Comment: @iphigenie 1.  questions should be supported by facts -> this is philosophy, not science.  I dont know the fact, all I have is my thought.  The reason why I asked for help was to convert that thought to a fact, by giving what ever i knew.  2.  can we even begin to realise why God did - i think we can begin it by finding out that god and asking him / in other words - being enlighetened.  3.   why do you think that God seeks the way we humans do? - I agree to this point.  The whole reason for asking a question is that we get some help.  Critics like you, how do you think your comments helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of creation in Eastern philosophy. Creation is a Judeo-Christian concept. Eastern philosophy says that that what we see as the universe is a 'projection'. What we see as the universe is a projection of God. You can't create something out of nothing, there is no logic in that. To see the universe as it truly is - God - is what is meant by enlightenment. The projection always was and always will be - it has no beginning and no end. It is eternal. You were born in a human body and your senses have been bombarding your mind since birth that what you senses present to your mind is real. The illusion is eternal, to escape the illusion is what is meant by enlightenment - to become aware of your true nature. When you achieve this you see the world as God, not what your senses have been mistakenly seeing it as. Control the mind, cut off the senses.

To ask why God created the world or why there is a projection is not a question that can be posed outside the sensual world. There is no why. "Why" only exists in the world of time space and causation. God is beyond the sensual world of time space and causation. For God to have a 'why' implies that God has a purpose in the creation - or projection - of the world, for God to have a purpose implies that God is not perfect. The syntax of your sentence is correct - Why did God create the world? - but good syntax does not imply good logic.

Comment: Vishwanada : Thank you. "For God to have a 'why' implies that God has a purpose in the creation - or projection - of the world, for God to have a purpose implies that God is not perfect."  - This was the most helpful.  Also, thank you for explaining impossible to explain, in the most easily understandable way.  Aum Namah Shivaya.